# Converting componentDidMount into a react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project of a mixture of componentDidMount and react hooks(terrible i know) however within one of the componentDidMount's I setState to allow for contractData to match the params of an Id as you can see below

```
componentDidMount = async() => {
    let tasks = [];

    try {
        tasks = await getTasks(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    catch (err) {
        if (err !== HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
            throw err;
        }
    }

    this.setState({ contract: await getContractData(this.props.match.params.id), tasks: tasks });
}
```

I need to do something similar about the params but for my getSupplierData within my useEffect

```
 const [suppliers, setSupplierList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getSupplierData().then(response => {
    setSupplierList(response);
  });
}, []);
```

How could i do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? (Other than not handling errors. ;-) )

Comment: Think there's a lack of what's needed here, do you want a complete like for like of the `componentDidMount` in React hooks? You say the hook version is related to completely different data though, think you need to give a bit more detail because as it stands what you have looks like it would work ok.

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't set `componentDidMount` to an `async` function, or if you do you need to ensure that it will never reject the promise it returns, since nothing in React is going to do anything with that promise. In the above, any error from `getTasks` other than `NOT_FOUND`, and any error at all from `getContractData`, will result in an unhandled rejection.